# How to get clang-format to align chained method calls

Tags: c++, clang-format

I've joined an existing project and I'm the first team member to use clang-format. The existing style mostly matches except for a couple of annoying differences. Here's one (the other one being [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742320/how-to-get-clang-format-to-put-closing-brackets-for-namespace-on-a-single-line)):

```
  folly::dynamic makeRequest(const string &response) {
    return folly::dynamic::object()
      ("log_type", "FOO")
      ("src_id", "42")
      ("dst_id", "666")
      ("success", true);
  }
```

clang-format insists on formatting it like this:

```
  folly::dynamic makeRequest(const string &token_response) {
    // using longer variable names to highlight using up the whole line lenght
    return folly::dynamic::object()("log_type", "FOO")(
        "src_id", somethingId)("dst_id", whateverId)("success",
                                                     sucess);
  }
```

In the former style I don't feel strongly for how continuation lines are indented, as long as we get one method invocation per line. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Not the best possible solution, but you can force line breaks by putting "//" after each line:

```
return folly::dynamic::object() //
  ("log_type", "FOO") //
  ("src_id", "42") //
  ("dst_id", "666") //
  ("success", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that I have used myself is to turn off `clang-format` for the specific block of code.

```
// clang-format off
return folly::dynamic::object()
    ("log_type", "FOO")
    ("src_id", "42")
    ("dst_id", "666")
    ("success", true)
    ;
// clang-format on
```

This might not be optimal if you have more complicated logic inside the chained method params (since you will want that logic to be formatted), but if you just have a tuple like this it can be cleaner than adding empty comments.

Both ways you are bypassing clang-format, but this way is cleaner (imo) and signifies your intentions more clearly to future developers.